# Non-ascii character error with only ascii code (\x83 character)

Tags: python, pygame, ascii

I'm getting the following error: `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\x83' in file sound.wav on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`

However, there are no non-ascii characters in my code. This is the code I'm using:

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("sound.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
  continue
```

As far as I can see, there are no non-ascii characters on line 2, never mind in the whole script.

I've tried adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the top of the file, but I still get the same error.

`\x83` is a 'no break here' character, but notepad++ shows no such character when 'show all characters' is checked.

Comment: The error message says the character is _in sound.wav_.

Comment: But that's a strange error (it's a binary file of course, why does it expect ASCII), no idea what causes it.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich You're right about it being a strange error, I didn't even realise it said that. I restarted my machine, and now I'm getting a different error that pygame can't read the wav file, so maybe it was confused before. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting the machine fixed the error. I'm still not sure what and why the error was being triggered, feel free to comment if you have any ideas.